# VBA: Creating new workbooks from list of values with VLookUps

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I've been searching and learning all I can about VBA before reaching out to the community.

I have a workbook with a sheet with a list of values. In another sheet that list is a dropdown in one of the cells. That cell is linked to dozens of vlookups and formulas to validate some company data quickly.

I've been fine tuning a macro from another post and have gotten it to copy the value from the list and save where I want it to and name it what I want. I have not gotten it to repeat the process though... Any advice? Here's the code I've been messing with so far.

```
Sub create()
Dim wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("GIW")
Set sh2 = Sheets("3A")
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr)
    For Each c In rng
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.Sheets.Add
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("D10") = c.Value
        wb.SaveAs c.Value & ".xlsx" = "C:\Users\ianc\Desktop\Exhibit 2 Data     Validation.xlsx"
        wb.Close False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to create a new *workbook* for each value, or a new *worksheet* ?

Comment: My list is a set of contract numbers. Those numbers are attached to a heap of vlookups to validate some performance data. I'd like to create a new copy of my entire workbook for each of those contract numbers in cell D10 to validate all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub create()

    Const FPATH As String = "C:\_Stuff\"

    Dim wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GIW")
    lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr)

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Sheets.Add before:=wb.Sheets(1)

    For Each c In rng
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("D10") = c.Value
        wb.SaveCopyAs FPATH & c.Value & ".xlsx"
    Next

    wb.Close False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see is using `ActiveWorkbook`. Try setting wb to the name of the workbook you are working with.

That is one of the first tricks to going from a recorded macro, you have to get rid of all of the `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` references that the recorder puts in a start using the specific names. VBA behaves better that way.